# Missing required parameters for [Route: form.comments.destroy] [URI: form/{form}/comments/{comment}](Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to implement a very simple destroy method for comments on a form, but I'm missing something I can't seem to put my finger on. Upon trying to run the view page, I get the error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Missing required parameters for [Route: form.comments.destroy] 
[URI: form/{form}/comments/{comment}]. 
(View: C:\distributor\resources\views\form\view.blade.php)
```

My routes file is set up as shown:

```
......
Route::resource('forms', 'FormController');
Route::get('/formSearch', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'FormController@formSearch']);

Route::resource('form.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

The form view file where the comments are displayed (and the method is trying to be called from) is set up as:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Comments</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse" id="comments" data-context="5" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="panel-body">
        @forelse ($form->comments as $comment)
          <div class="form-group">
            Comment By: <strong>{{ $comment->user_name }}</strong> at <strong>{{ $comment->created_at }}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <div class="form-control" readonly>{{ $comment->comment }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group col-md-2">
            <form action="{{ route('form.comments.destroy', $comment->id) }}" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this comment?" value="delete">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        @empty
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control" readonly>No Comments Found</div>
          </div>
        @endforelse
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">
            <a href="#">Back To Top</a>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Finally, in the controller the method is set up as:

```
public function destroy($id){
$comment = Comment::find($id);
$comment->delete();

// Redirect
return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Comment successfully deleted');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend rename your `form.comments` route to `comments` because you got path `form/{form}/comments/{comment}` so 2 parameters required for it. `form` and `comment`. You send only 1 (`$comment->id`)

```
// Route::resource('form.comments', 'CommentsController');
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');


<form action="{{ route('comments.destroy', $comment->id) }}" method="POST">...
```

Comment: This fixed it! I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that, thank you very much!